# How can I render my camera view when I also have an MP4 in the sequencer?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render from my active camera but it keeps coming up as a frame from the MP4 animatic i'm using as reference. How can i render from my 3D scene?

Please and thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the MP4 is only in the *Sequencer*, you can disable it from the render *Pipeline* in the *Output Properties* under *Post Processing*:

[image: output properties]

Comment: Amazing, thanks Gordon.